# How can I display a buffer in a whole frame, removing the rest in the act?

Tags: buffers, window, frames

Basically that. I need a function that would do this when I open a buffer in a frame with many other windows. Maybe Emacs has one by default.

Comment: Does this question and answer help any ("*How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame*")?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  If you want to get rid of the other windows in the target frame, just add `(delete-other-windows)` after the target window has acquired focus.  The answer in the linked thread targets the largest window in the frame, but that is a custom function and can be changed to do anything under the sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```lisp
(defun switch-buffer-delete-other-windows ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'switch-to-buffer)
  (delete-other-windows))

(defun find-file-delete-other-windows ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'find-file)
  (delete-other-windows))
```

and so on…?

Answer (score 0):

`C-x 5 2` does what you request: it opens the current buffer in a separate frame. But it does not delete the original window showing the buffer in the original frame.

Command `tear-off-window` does both: opens the buffer in a separate frame *and* deletes its window from the original frame.

Personally, I bind `tear-off-window` to `C-x 5 1`. (I don't use that key's original binding of `delete-other-frames`.)

Comment: Thanks, when I do tear-off-window (in a split vertically window), it opens a new frame with my buffer, but inside two windows. What I need is a one window, in one frame solution :)

Comment: Sorry; I don't understand. A frame inside two windows? Maybe you're reversing the meanings of "frame" and "window"? No idea what you're saying now.

Comment: My apologies. I meant: "when I do tear-off-window (in a split vertically window), it opens a new frame with my buffer, but inside THERE ARE two windows. What I need is a one window, in one frame solution :)"

Comment: Do you see that if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file). I don't. I don't see that with either a vertically split window (`C-x 3`) or a horizontally split window (`C-x 2`). If you don't see that with `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Yes, I must have something in my init. Thanks!